# Cloud Firestore Authentication not working using PHP

Tags: php, firebase, authentication, google-cloud-firestore, rules

I am new to firebase. I am testing a web application using the Firestore Database and PHP. https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-firestore. I have created a database "cities" and want to fetch the data only for the login User. I have set a rule on the database

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /cities/{city} {
       allow read, write: if request.auth != null
    }
   
  }
}
```

Now after login is successful using email and password, I want to fetch the population of a city. I have checked firebase auth and it is showing me logged in.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    var uid = user.uid;
    console.log("Logged In"+uid)
  } else {
    console.log("Please login");
  }
});
```

I am using the following PHP code.

```
$firestore = new FirestoreClient([
        'projectId' => 'XXXXXXXX',
        
    ]);

$collectionReference = $firestore->collection('cities'); 
$documentReference = $collectionReference->document('kolkata');
$snapshot = $documentReference->snapshot();
echo "Population is " . $snapshot['population'];
```

Now I am getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException: {
> "message": "Missing or insufficient permissions.", "code": 7,
> "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED", "details": [] }

Now when I change the security rule to allow read and write for all users, data are fetching properly.

I have searched the document but have not found any suggestions about the error.

Also, when I am using the **keyfile** along with the project id, I can fetch the data, but there is another issue. The security rule is not working anymore. I can read the data without logging in.
How can I solve this issue. Thanks in advance and sorry for the bad English.

```
$firestore = new FirestoreClient([
        'projectId' => 'XXXXXX',
        'keyFile' => json_decode(file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/secret/XXXXXXXX.json'), true)
    ]);
```

Comment: did you solve this issue?